# finagleのClientサンプルについて

Tags: scala

finagleのClientサンプルをURLを変えて動かしてみたのですが、
responseが「400 bad request」となってしまいます。
（URLはブラウザでアクセスできることを確認しています）

どうすれば「200 OK」のresuponseを受け取れるようになるのでしょうか？

```
val client: Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] =
    Http.newService("localhost:80")
val request =  new DefaultHttpRequest(
    HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/")
val response: Future[HttpResponse] = client(request)

response onSuccess { resp: HttpResponse =>
    println("GET success: " + resp)  //「GET success: Response("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request")」が出力される
}
Await.ready(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すいません。解決しました。

HttpHeaderのHOSTが指定されていなかったため、Serverに弾かれているようでした。
以下のようにHOSTを設定することで正常に通信できるようになりました。

```
val request =  new DefaultHttpRequest(
    HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.GET, "/")
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST, "localhost")
```